Можно ли менять описание эмбеда?
Возникла такая проблема: Нужно чтобы после прохождения 2 секунд описание эмбеда менялось с 123 на 456. Можно ли это как-то сделать без пересоздания или создания нового эмбеда?
async def __миниигра(ctx):
    emb_text = 123
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='<:l_s_r:1302749029570183319>┃Мини-игра',
    description=f'{emb_text}',
    colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0)
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Запросил {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar}')
  embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/1296444016161718322/45bb7a156802c28018ad0ebbd285682f.png?size=2048')
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    emb_text = 456
    await msg.edit(embed=embed)```


Как вариант, можно Embed сохранять во внешнюю переменную или внешний список Embed-ов, в качестве шаблонов, а потом через редактирование сообщения присваивать сообщению ютот же Embed только с другим текстом
